# Laravel chunk withcount and where

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want a list with a select group of users, where I can see how many clicks they have starting from a specific date. `Clicks` is a table with a few million rows, the sweet chunk spot for me was something around 250 000 to 500 000 as the chunk value. (This SQL Query took 2.4 seconds)

```
SELECT c.user_id, u.name, count(*) as aantal 
from clicks c
    join users u on c.user_id = u.id
where c.updated_at > '2020/02/09 20:00' and c.user_id not in (1, 3, 16, 18, 19, 20)
GROUP BY user_id;
```

For all the clicks per user does this query works:

```
$users= User::has('clicks')
->withCount('clicks')
->orderBy('clicks_count', 'desc')
->get()
->whereNotIn('id', [1, 3, 16, 18, 19, 20])
->transform(function ($item) {
    // Remove all fields that you don't use inside the view
    unset($item->created_at, $item->updated_at, $item->admin, $item->email_verified_at);
    return $item;
});
```

For getting the total click count I found this:

```
$count = 0;
Click::chunk(500000, function($clicks) use (&$count)
{
    $count = $count + count($clicks);
});
```

I tried some queries but nothing worked so far.

I was thinking of something like:

```
$users = User::whereNotIn('id', [1, 3, 16, 18, 19, 20])->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    // Here find all CLicks for this user with later then a date with a Chunk
}
```

But then you would go through all (few 2-4) millions of rows for every user, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to go a lot of contradicting approaches, in my opinion when dealing with big amounts of data, let `sql` do as much as you can. The following query will get you all the data you want.

```
Users::join('clicks', 'clicks.user_id', '=', 'u.id')->where('clicks.updated_at', '>', '2020/02/09 20:00')->whereNotIn('users.id', [1, 3, 16, 18, 19, 20]);
```

When you join data like so, `sql` will have the rows with each users repeated as many clicks they have, so we have to squash the data back with group by.

```
...->groupBy('users.id');
```

Use an aggregate to get the amount of clicks they have.

```
...->select('users.id', DB::raw('count(clicks.id) as clicks'));
```

This will only fill the users.id and a field called clicks with the amount of clicks. Thou it should avoid you to having do anything with chunk. If foreign keys is setup, this query should be perform good.

The full query should look similar to this. You can't select extra fields due to the group by, but utilizing aggregates function max or min, can circumvent that.

```
Users::join('clicks', 'clicks.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
    ->where('clicks.updated_at', '>', '2020/02/09 20:00')
    ->whereNotIn('users.id', [1, 3, 16, 18, 19, 20])
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->select('users.id', DB::raw('count(clicks.id) as clicks'))
    ->get();
```